# How to identify and remove a closing connection in ws-rs?

Tags: websocket, rust

I have a basic server made with ws-rs that holds a list of connections. When a connection closes, I'd like to be able to tell which connection it is and remove it from the list.

I'd like to achieve something like this:

```rust
extern crate ws; // 0.9.1

use ws::{listen, CloseCode, Handler, Sender};

struct Connection {
    ip: String,
}

struct MyHandler {
    out: Sender,
    connections: Vec<Connection>,
}

impl Handler for MyHandler {
    fn on_close(&mut self, code: CloseCode, reason: &str) {
        // here I'd like to identify the connection
        // but there doesn't seem to be any interface for it
    }
}

fn main() {
    listen("127.0.0.1:8001", |out| MyHandler {
        out,
        connections: Vec::new(),
    })
    .unwrap();
}
```

I feel like it's pretty basic to want to keep a list of connections, and I'm missing something obvious. I can't seem to find any resources online about this.

Comment: @Shepmaster thank you, I added something that isn't pseudo-code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer over at [r/rust](https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/7drfuv/trying_to_understand_websockets/dq1kjld?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x).

This question is a case of googling the wrong question. I misunderstood the usage of [Handler](https://ws-rs.org/api_docs/ws/trait.Handler.html). I assumed there was just one `Handler` (for each thread), but a `Handler` is meant to represent a connection. Keeping a list of them is the same as keeping a list of connections, each of which is identifiable by a [Sender](https://ws-rs.org/api_docs/ws/struct.Sender.html#method.token) instance created for each connection.